# Stuck in CSV file on Windows 7 by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, windows-7

I want to create a CSV file on Windows 7 by PowerShell script. Now I have

```
$dd = @(Get-Date -Format d)
$report = @()
$index = 0
foreach ($Item in $dd) {
    [array]$report += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Date = $dd[$index]
    }
    $index++
}
$report | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\test.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

After I ran the code I got something like this:

```
"IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Keys","Values","SyncRoot","Count"
"False","False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Object","5"
```

But I want a proper CSV file like this:

```
"Date"
"11/3/2017"
```

Is it possible by PowerShell?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `$dd` will only ever contain 1 value, the current date.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted should do exactly what you want. However, it's using the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator that was introduced with PowerShell v3, whereas Windows 7 ships with PowerShell v2.

You have basically 3 options:

- Upgrade to PowerShell v3 or newer.
- Use the `New-Object` cmdlet instead of the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator:

  ```
  $dd | ForEach-Object {
      New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
          Date = $dd[$index]
      }
  } | Export-Csv ...
  ```
- Use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

  ```
  $dd | Select-Object @{n='Date';e={$_}} | Export-Csv ...
  ```

Comment: I deleted my answer as yours is better.